# ionic-native-google-maps displaying map correctly (setting target & location) but not responding to any gesture or button click

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic-native-google-maps, but the map keeps showing but no responding to any interaction. I already checked that there isn't any HTML element over the map, and I haven't disabled any button or gesture in the map options.

**component.ts**

```
  import {
    GoogleMaps,
    GoogleMap,
    GoogleMapOptions,
    GoogleMapsMapTypeId
  } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

  ... class definition

  map: GoogleMap;

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.order = history.state.data.order;
    await this.platform.ready();
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    const deliveryPosition = {
      lat: this.order.delivery_location.latitude,
      lng: this.order.delivery_location.longitude,
    }

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      mapType: GoogleMapsMapTypeId.HYBRID,
      camera: {
        target: deliveryPosition,
        zoom: 18,
      },
      controls: {
        myLocationButton: true,
        myLocation: true,
        zoom: true,
        compass: false,
      },
      gestures: {
        tilt: false,
      },
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding-horizontal ion-padding-bottom">
  <div id="map_canvas">

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: sure, @SergeyRudenko, I updated my question to show it